# WKWebView intercept local file requests

Tags: ios, swift, local, wkwebview, wknavigationdelegate

I have a WKWebView in my iOS 11+ app where I need to load custom HTML from local in-memory HTML. I can accomplish this by using `webView.loadHTMLString` or `webview.load(data)`, which is working fine.

This HTML references some required .js/.css/.png files. For normal web URL requests, WKWebView will just do this on the fly, loading missing files. But in this case, I need to intercept these requests, and provide the file contents, as some of it needs to be dynamically generated. So the .css files etc. I need to serve are not physically present as local files.

I thought this would be just a matter of implementing the `decidePolicyFor` methods of the `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol, but for some reason this is not triggered for local subrequests, so how can I accomplish this?

I also tried saving the HTML as a local temporary file and loading it using `webView.load(URLRequest)`, but that does not trigger the delegate either. If it was a web URL, it triggers fine.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you render `fullIosAppPath/page.html` which has text like `<img src="folder/1.png">`. 
In such case you need to have a file `fullIosAppPath/folder/1.png` in your app's folder. The `WKWebView` will load `1.png` without any interception - it will just render the image.

So you can parse the HTML file before rendering it, and generate/load the requires resources like `1.png`. 
You can parse an HTML file with frameworks like [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna), or write some simple parser by yourself.